# Linking target failed for lib with X11 (c++)

Tags: ninja, meson-build

I am converting CMake C++ project to meson. One thing left to run it properly.
I use in my project lib a X11 library.

With CMake, project linking works correctly:

```sh
...

target_link_libraries(hamster ui util ${GTKMM_LIBRARIES} ${X11_LIBRARIES} -lX11 -lXtst -lXext)
```

How to add `-lX11 -lXtst -lXext` flags to meson project? I tried some solutions like `link_args` but it did not help. I receive:

```sh
ninja: Entering directory `build'
[17/19] Linking target src/ui_lib/libui.so.
FAILED: src/ui_lib/libui.so

/home/repos/project/build/../src/ui_lib/ui/window/WindowBody.cpp:583: undefined reference to `XTestGrabControl'
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer below:

```sh
gtkmm_dep = dependency('gtkmm-3.0')
x11_dep = dependency('x11')
xtst_dep = dependency('xtst')
xext_dep = dependency('xext')

ui = library('ui', dependencies : [gtkmm_dep, x11_dep, xtst_dep, xext_dep, util_dep],
    sources : [
        'ui/window/WindowBody.h', 'ui/window/WindowBody.cpp',
    ]
)

ui_dep = declare_dependency(
    include_directories : include_directories('.'),
    link_with : ui
)
```